# How to Print Ticket with QrCode in POS Machine using React Native?

Tags: react-native, qr-code, thermal-printer, printers, bluetooth-printing

I want to print a Ticket in POS Device With QRCODE so how to print?

That POS Machine is a Bluetooth printer so how to print in this Ticket.

For that i m using a react-native-thermal-receipt-printer npm module but in this i m not able to print a QRCODE Please Help to solve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.